# What is the most commercially successful movie adaption of a video game?

Tags: box-office, video-game-adaptation

I was listening to a talk show predicting flops this summer and it was argued that upcoming video game adaptations would be flops.

So I was wondering which video game adaptations had been commercially successful, and which individual movie has made the most money at the box office? Tomb Raider comes to mind. I don't think Wing Commander was a big hit...

Comment: Ooh, is it Super Mario Bros?

Comment: You mean [What went wrong with Super Mario Bros?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/what-went-wrong-with-super-mario-bros?rq=1)

Comment: Hey, Super Mario Bros made a perfectly good RiffTrax. SUCCESS! My guess is **Resident Evil.** 6 movies. From wikiedia "Despite constant negative reviews, with five films released, the Resident Evil film series is the highest-grossing film series to be based on video games of all time, having grossed US$915 million worldwide. It is set to conclude on January 27, 2017 with a sixth film, Resident Evil: The Final Chapter, written and directed by Anderson."

Comment: @user7812 - Yes, it ***is*** Super Mario Bros, you sarcastic time-traveller, you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the years since the last answer was released a couple of films have topped it in the global box-office

[Warcraft](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=warcraft.htm) earned $433.7M in 2016

[Rampage](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=newlinetentpole2018.htm) earned $428.0M in 2018

[The Angry Birds Movie](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=angrybirds.htm) earned $352.3M in 2016 as well

[Detective Pikachu](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=detectivepikachu.htm) earned $431.6M in 2019

[Sonic The Hedgehog](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl4244997633/) earned $319M in 2020

[Sonic The Hedgehog 2](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl1363641089/) earned $405M in 2022

[The Super Mario Bros. Movie](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/title/tt6718170/) earned $1.4B in 2023!!

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised *Warcraft* beat *Detective Pikachu*

Comment: The Super Mario Bros Movie is now over $1.1 billion.

Comment: Very true, although I’m not sure it’s completely done in box offices worldwide

Answer (score 12):

Based on this list of "most successful movie [*franchise*](http://www.the-numbers.com/movies/franchises/)", the first Video-game-to-movie translation I can see is:

> **Resident Evil**

Which wikipedia reports has earned more than $900m in ticket sales across 7 films, internationally.

---

The single highest grossing [*individual film*](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/world/?pagenum=4&p=.htm) appears to be

> **Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time**

which earned its studio over $300M at the box office.

Comment: It's indeed Resident Evil franchise, but it earned more than 900m from just 5 movies

Comment: I did expected that, anyways there is one more Resident Evil  film going to come to change the figures.

Comment: The fact that there are five *Resident Evil* films goes to show there's profit in them. Video game movie sequels seem to be the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - What I found intriguing is just how few there were in the top hundred, just one or two.

Comment: What a strange world we live in, *The Angry Birds Movie* beat *The Prince of Persia: The Sands of Time* at the Box office

Comment: I specifically asked this question because I thought _The Angry Birds Movie_ was going to be a flop, so this twist is ironic.

Comment: The sequel  *The Angry Birds Movie 2* is probably not going to top the original

Answer (score 8):

As of July 2023, ***[The Super Mario Bros. Movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6718170/)*** (2023) is the highest-grossing film based on a video game. Its worldwide box office gross is $1.3B, according to [The Numbers](https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/Super-Mario-Bros-Movie-The-(2022)#tab=box-office) and [Box Office Mojo](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/title/tt6718170/). It has surpassed the second-place film, *Warcraft* (2016), by a huge margin.

*Pokémon* still holds the crown for the highest-grossing film franchise based on a video game, with a $1.5B worldwide box office gross. ([Sources](https://web.archive.org/web/20230728043653/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films_based_on_video_games#endnote_Franchise_sources%C2%A7))